# Is there a term for outdoor adventure activities like camping, hiking, trekking?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Outdoor adventure activities seems like a mouthful, so I was wondering if there was a more appropriate term for such activities in the language?

Wikipedia suggests 'Outdoor Recreation' but that implies these to be leisure based activities and doesn't account for people like me for whom it is a serious passion or pursuit.

What would be some alternative terms that encompass these activities? One that comes to mind is 'wilderness adventures'.

Comment: This (ELU) is the place to ask that question, but you may also be interested in The Great Outdoors SE  http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/  Throw in back-country skiing, geocaching, climbing.....my mind is a blank for an umbrella term.  Often  these activities are done in wilderness or at least backcountry, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

*[Outdoor recreation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outdoor_recreation)* or *mountain recreation* is the normal phrase. People who are passionate about hiking, backpacking, etc. will use this phrase, although it is, as you observe, a little passionless.

More passionate alternatives include *[mountaineering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountaineering)*, *[mountain sport](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_sport)*, *alpine sport*, and *[alpinism](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/alpinism)*.

These terms are sometimes used with special, restrictive definitions, but they can be used more generally to encompass the types of activities you describe, so long as those activities occur in the mountains.

Another alternative is *adventure sports*, which has the advantage of not being limited in application to mountain activities. I am not sure how robust the convention of using this phrase to cover your types of activities is, but it could be used fairly obviously to cover them. That said, [extreme sports](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_sport) like skydiving are *sometimes* called *adventurous sports*, which might cause some confusion.

Another alternative is *outdoor sports*, which can pretty obviously be used to cover your types of activities given that *outdoor* now carries strong connotations of camping, woods, etc. (think of an *outdoorsman*). That said, the term could also be used to mean any sport played out of doors (for example, football). This might cause some confusion. A similar problem arises for *outdoor activities*.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! What is the connotation of the word 'sports' in there? Does it imply competition or competitive-ness?

Comment: "sports" usually connotes *competitive* sports like football or tennis, but it can also be used more generally to connote any ability requiring prowess. Dictionary.com defines it as: "an athletic activity requiring skill or physical prowess *and often of a competitive nature*". Notice the hedge "and *often* of a..."

Answer (score 1):

## **Outdoorsmanship**

> noun, plural **outdoorsmen**.
>
> 1. a person devoted to outdoor sports and recreational activities, as hiking, hunting, fishing, or camping.
> 2. a person who spends much time in the outdoors

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/outdoorsmanship

Answer (score 0):

Despite the rejection of it in the question, I think *Outdoor recreation* fits the described activities perfectly well.  It's clearly all outdoor, and the word *recreation* means:

[OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recreation):

> [mass noun] Activity done for enjoyment when one is not working.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recreation):

> something people do to relax or have fun : activities done for enjoyment

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recreation#Noun):

> Any activity, such as play, that amuses, diverts or stimulates.

The overwhelming majority of people walking in the woods do so because they enjoy it.  Exceptions would be:

- For-profit berry-picking.
- Camping while on a scientific expedition, while collecting reindeer poo or other fun.  While people might still have fun at this, it wouldn't be called recreation.
- Park rangers patrolling trails.
- People walking as some sort of penance, such as some religious pilgrims.

However, those exceptions are mostly few and far between.  Using the phrase *outdoor recreation* is unlikely to cause misunderstandings.